# como recorrer un array de objetos con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tengo el siguiente *json*

```
[  
 {"id":1, "proveedor_id":1, "nombre":"ham Clasica", "precio":3}, 
 {"id":2, "proveedor_id":1, "nombre":"ham Alioli", "precio":4.8}, 
 {"id":3, "proveedor_id":1, "nombre":"ham Guayanesa", "precio":4.5}, 
 {"id":4, "proveedor_id":1, "nombre":"ham New York", "precio":5.6}, 
 {"id":5, "proveedor_id":1, "nombre":"ham Tender Crispy", "precio":5.7}, 
 {"id":6, "proveedor_id":1, "nombre":"ham Chicken Roma", "precio":5.5}, 
 {"id":7, "proveedor_id":1, "nombre":"ham Steak Lomito", "precio":6.2}  
]
```

...y lo recibo a través de este código:

```
query.done(function(data) {
    JSON.parse(data);
});
```

Mi pregunta es ¿cómo recorrer y obtener todos los valores del *json* para posteriormente desplegarlo en una tabla *html* con *jquery* o *js*?

---

me sale siguiente error en cosola

```
jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in [{"id":1,"proveedor_id":1,"nombre":"ham Clasica","precio":3},{"id":2,"proveedor_id":1,"nombre":"ham Alioli","precio":4.8},{"id":3,"proveedor_id":1,"nombre":"ham Guayanesa","precio":4.5},{"id":4,"proveedor_id":1,"nombre":"ham New York","precio":5.6},{"id":5,"proveedor_id":1,"nombre":"ham Tender Crispy","precio":5.7},{"id":6,"proveedor_id":1,"nombre":"ham Chicken Roma","precio":5.5},{"id":7,"proveedor_id":1,"nombre":"ham Steak Lomito","precio":6.2}]
at p (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
at Function.each (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:29)
at c (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
at l (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
```

y utilicé el .each de esta manera:

```
query.done(function (data) {
    JSON.parse(data);
    $.each(data, (index, value) =>{
      console.log(value);
    });
});
```

Comment: Con un [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for), [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach), [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...of), [`while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/while)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes iterarlos con `$.each` de `jQuery` de la siguiente manera:

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"proveedor_id":1,"nombre":"ham Clasica","precio":3},{"id":2,"proveedor_id":1,"nombre":"ham Alioli","precio":4.8},{"id":3,"proveedor_id":1,"nombre":"ham Guayanesa","precio":4.5},{"id":4,"proveedor_id":1,"nombre":"ham New York","precio":5.6},{"id":5,"proveedor_id":1,"nombre":"ham Tender Crispy","precio":5.7},{"id":6,"proveedor_id":1,"nombre":"ham Chicken Roma","precio":5.5},{"id":7,"proveedor_id":1,"nombre":"ham Steak Lomito","precio":6.2}];

$.each(data, (index, value) =>{
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

En caso de querer usar los valores de cada objeto, seria bueno hacerlo de esta manera:

```js
const table = $("#table");
const data = [
  {"id":1,"proveedor_id":1,"nombre":"ham Clasica","precio":3},
  {"id":2,"proveedor_id":1,"nombre":"ham Alioli","precio":4.8},
  {"id":3,"proveedor_id":1,"nombre":"ham Guayanesa","precio":4.5},
  {"id":4,"proveedor_id":1,"nombre":"ham New York","precio":5.6},
  {"id":5,"proveedor_id":1,"nombre":"ham Tender Crispy","precio":5.7},
  {"id":6,"proveedor_id":1,"nombre":"ham Chicken Roma","precio":5.5},
  {"id":7,"proveedor_id":1,"nombre":"ham Steak Lomito","precio":6.2}
];

$.each(data, (index, value) =>{

  const row = $(document.createElement("tr"));
  const secRow = $(document.createElement("tr"));
  
  for(let prop in value){
  
    if(index === 0){
      
      const cellHead = $(document.createElement("th"));
      cellHead.text(prop);
      secRow.append(cellHead);
      table.append(secRow);
      
    }
    
    const cell = $(document.createElement("td"));
    cell.text(value[prop]);
    row.append(cell);
    
  }
  
  table.append(row);
});
```

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}

tr, td, th{
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

td, th{
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id = "table">
</table>
```

Donde con `$.each` iteramos sobre el array de objetos.

Con `document.createElement` originario de `JS puro` creamos objetos del `DOM` tal como `filas`, `columnas` y `celdas` de la tabla.

con `text()` originario de los elementos de `jQuery` añadimos a un element, texto de contenido.

por ultimo con `append()` de `jQuery` añadimos algun elemento de jQuery creado a otro.

Entonces en resumen, primero recorremos todos los objetos del `array de objetos` con `$.each` y luego recorremos las propiedades de cada objeto con un ciclo `for-in`.

Comment: hola bro pero el data lo recibo desde un archivo php que me lo envia en forma json, en eso caso solo paso directamente al .each? igual ya probare a ver

Comment: listo ya pude resolver gracias amigo!

Answer (score 0):

lo que pasa es que estas haciendo un JSON parse pero no estas almacenando ese JSON parse, entonces es como si nunca lo hicieras

```
query.done(function (data) {
    var dataParseado = JSON.parse(data);
    $.each(dataParseado, (index, value) =>{
      console.log(value);
    });
});
```

Comment: Si!! me di cuenta hace rato, esto era ! gracias!